# Detect invalid value in yaml during Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: ansible, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo of ansible vars (YAML) files.

Ideally, I would like to "lint" this during a stage of my Azure Pipelines build pipeline, and fail if anything other than `Demo` is found in an `organization` key.

An example document could look like this:

```
team_org: 'demo'

#INVENTORY
controller_inventories:
  - name: Demo Inventory
    organization: Demo
    description: Demo Inventory

controller_credentials:
  - name: My Credential
    organization: '{{ team_org }}'
    credential_type: Machine Credential

controller_templates:
  - name: Hello World
    organization: Not Demo
    job_type: run
    inventory: Demo Inventory
    project: hello-world-project
    execution_environment: Default Execution Environment
    playbook: playbooks/hello_world/main.yml
```

So the only error in my example would be on the line representing `controller_templates[0].organization`.

My current solution looks like this using a `grep` in a simple bash step:

```
- bash: |
    if grep "Organization:.*" -rni --include=\*.yml --include=\*.yaml ./ | grep -vi  "organization:\s*$aap_org\s*"; then
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Detected an orgnization that is not yours ($aap_org). View execution for more details."
      exit 1
    fi
  env:
    aap_org: $(org_name)
```

This *works*... kind of. Since the YAML is not actually being interpreted, it fails when referencing the `team_org` variable via the jinja templating syntax. It also has the potential to catch unintentional variables/comments that use the term `organization:`.

Its also worth mentioning, that it is unknown how many root objects there can be in the file. SO I can't simple iterate over a finite list of root objects looking specifically for a key/value.

Are there any tools/libraries that can do this?

Thanks!